# I use AppsScript to create draft email with ICS attachment, however Gmail web removes the attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, icalendar

Below script creates a draft email.  If I look at the draft in Outlook it has 2 attachments, one text, one a meeting invite (ICS).  If I send it from outlook it arrives with 2 attachments.
However, if I look at the draft in Gmail in a browser, the ICS attachment has gone.

```
function ICStest(){
  var mytitle="hi", myUUID = Utilities.getUuid(), myShortDesc=mytitle;
  var myICS=`
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:${mytitle}
DTSTART:20240104T093000Z
DTEND:20240104T133000Z
DTSTAMP:20240121T164157Z
UID:${myUUID}
DESCRIPTION:${myShortDesc}
STATUS:CONFIRMED
PRIORITY:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
`;
var myoptions = {attachments:[{fileName:"test.ics", content:myICS,mimeType:'text/calendar'},{fileName:"test2.txt", content:"Stuff",mimeType:'text/plain'}]};
GmailApp.createDraft("me@gmail.com","Test","Hi",myoptions);
}
```

[Here it is in Outlook with 2 attachments:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Y2k.png)

[Here it is in gmail web with only 1 attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdQAS.png)

I want to create a draft email with attached meeting invite from code, edit it to personalise, then send an email from gmail web with an ICS attachment intact.  I can do this using outlook, but not using gmail web - the ICS attachment disappears, but the text attachment remains.

I can't assume all my users will have outlook, many use outlook web, and it just doesn't work!
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't managed to fix this problem.  A workaround is to store the ICS data into a Google Drive file, then attach a link to the file, something like:

```
var myfolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(ICSFolderId);
var myfile = myfolder.createFile(myFileName, myICS, 'text/calendar');
myfile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
var myURL = `https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=${myfile.getId()}&confirm=xxx`;
var mylink0=`<a href="${myURL}">Add to calendar (.ics)</a>`;
```

This creates a new file named 'myFileName' in a folder of my choice, sets the permissions so anyone with the link can view it, then builds a URL to the download link of the file.  This works well on iphone, and avoids using an attachment.
Not a solution, but better than nothing.